# Show that $\det_i(A)$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=(C_1,C_2,...,C_n)$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with columns $C_1,C_2,...,C_n$.

If the column $C_k$ is the sum of other two columns of $A$, say $C_k=C^´_k+C^{''}_k$ for some $k$. Then show that

$$\det_i(C_1,C_2,...,C^´_k+C^{''}_k,...,C_n)$$$$=\det_i(C_1,C_2,...,C^{'}_k,...,C_n)+\det_i(C_1,C_2,...,C^{''}_k,...,C_n),$$

where $\displaystyle\det_i(A)=
\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\det(A_{ij})
$ and $i$ is a fixed row, and $A_{ij}$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ removing the $i$-th row and $j$-th column.

I was trying by induction on $n$,
but I get nowhere any hint? Thank you!

Comment: What is $A_{ij}$?

Comment: @Mason The matrix obtained from removing the i-row and j-column

Comment: Hint: Relate $\det_i$ to $\det$. In more detal, note that $\det(A) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(-1)^{i + j}a_{ij}\det(A_{ij})$. Let $B$ be the same as $A$ but with $b_{ij} = (-1)^{i + j}a_{ij}$ for $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. Then $\det(B) = \det_i(A)$.